# How do I edit the data for these named Shader UV attributes?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am working with a third-party Blender model and the creator is using what appears to be named attributes for the UV Map node: "meatball," "feather" "UVMap". What I cannot figure out is how to edit this data. Can I edit it? If yes, then how? Where is it? Thanks. Blender 3.6, Windows 11

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by editing the data? Like you can (probably) just use it like any other coordinate system. Like using a mapping node after that UV output is also called editing. Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I changed the source images for the Texture nodes which have a different ratio (1:1 instead of 1:2), but the UV Map node is imposing the old ratio (1:2) onto the Texture nodes. How do I edit these UV Map nodes to make them 1:1?

Comment: If I understood what you said, then use a mapping node and just scale by 2 on the necessary axis.

Comment: Edit your question and add these details as well. If possible add the images of the changed ratios as well. You are an old member, kinda expected you to be precise enough.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be any more precise. I like the current placement and scale of these textures, so all I want to do is edit the current image ratio values. Maybe I'm wrong, but I presuming that somewhere the UV data for "meatball," "feather" and "UVMap" are stored in the Blender file, but where? I'm thinking that if I can find those, then I can edit them directly without too much fuss.

Comment: Ok so those are UV mps right? So selecting the one (in the obj data properties panel)you need to edit and opening the UV editor will give you access to that UV Map. You can change the map however you want.

Comment: Via the UV Editor then. There's a gaping hole in my knowledge when it comes to UVs. Thanks! :)